# Unable to dismiss keyboard with UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios-simulator

I cannot get textFieldShouldEndEditing to call. I have re created the links in interface builder and tried, but nothing seems to work. Any idea why this would not be called?

**Edit**

I am implementing both -textFieldShouldEndEditing and -textFieldDidFinishEditing. Adding the delegate for the textField didnt help either. The code I am using below is not triggering the log messages.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"Done editing...");
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"Done editing...");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `-textFieldDidEndEditing`. That gets called after the text field resigns first responder... which it hasn't yet because you haven't told it to because that method hasn't been called yet because first responder hasn't been resigned because you haven't told it to yet. Circular, chicken-and-egg sort of problem.

The delegate method you want is `-textFieldShouldReturn`. That gets called when the "return" key is pressed. Inside that, tell the text field to resign first responder, then return `YES`.

Also put a big clear custom button behind your form, and hook its touch-up-inside to a method that goes through all the text fields in the form and resigns first responder on each of them. So a background touch releases the keyboard too.

Answer (score 2):

I saw it was a long-long time ago and I hope that since then you could solve the problem. Everybody tells you the right thing, but you have to take care of all at the same time! Let me just go through on all of them:

1. Make the promise first:

> ```
> @interface yourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
> ```

1. Then make sure, you also hook up your textfields' delegates on the storyboard to the actual viewcontroller (yourViewController)!
2. When its done, implement the method in the right viewcontroller file (yourViewController.m):

> ```
>  - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
>        [textField resignFirstResponder];
>        return YES;
>  }
> ```

1. Test it, and it should work now...

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

set the delegate to your TextField

In the interface Builder select your TextField, then press command + 2(Connections) and connect the delegate outled with the file's owner then save, and with that should work.

the delegate method are:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

 }

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

 }
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the delegate?

If not,set using

```
textField.delegate=self;
```

or else,

You must include UITextFieldDelegate in .h file

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

**EDIT:**

You have to code in this delegate **textFieldDidEndEditing** not this **textFieldShouldEndEditing**